# Do I need any specific hardware and/or software to use Mechatrolink for communication?

Tags: communication

I googled it and know that it is a communication protocol.

My question is that whether I need any specific hardware and/or software to use [Mechatrolink](http://www.mechatrolink.org/en/index.html) for communication?

Also if possible, please tell me the advantage to use Mechatrolink. Thanks

Comment: "advantage" of using it? Well, I want to surf the web so I would rather use WiFi with my laptop. We really need to know about you specific use-case to answer something like that.

Comment: I've never heard of it, but I'm not into automation and controls. It seems to me you didn't Google hard enough. http://www.mechatrolink.org/en/mechatrolink/apl.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Physical layer support is defined [here on their site](http://www.mechatrolink.org/en/mechatrolink/spec.html). If you take a look:
[image: Picture of specification]

You are either going to support RS-485 or Ethernet. Once you are above that step you probably can be lazy and implement the rest in software. I would need a full specification to read to tell you for sure.